# excel solver more than 200 data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am new using this Solver function. Is there is way to use Solver for more than 200 sets of data. Maybe using VBA? Really hope someone could help me

Comment: Yes, check the [OpenSolver](http://opensolver.org/) add-in. You build the model in solver as you do, but then you click "QuickSolve" from the "OpenSolver" tab instead of "Solve". No need to use VBA

Comment: Hi. Did the answer below help in understanding how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to buy their commercial product (from Frontline Systems) or build one yourself. For Linear/Non-linear optimization there are a lot of open source libraries available in C++ so you may compile a DLL and invoke it from a VBA wrapper.

Also, it's not difficult to implement it completely in VBA. The original guys who developed the solver have given a very very detailed explanation of its workings here. These are the guys who actually made it so you can easily replicate it - especially for the linear case.

A bit dated, but will give you an idea on how to proceed.

https://www.utexas.edu/courses/lasdon/design.htm

Especially useful are the sections where they describe how they build the Jacobian matrix numerically (for Generalized Gradient Descent in NLopt) and how they use a small perturbation to determine the linear coefficients for the Simplex Method. Thus for a linear problem, the only trick is to generate the Coefficient Matrix and then the solver can proceed completely in-memory and generate

1. the optimal solution
2. Shadow prices, reduced costs, etc.

Comment: Implementing an LP solver is not that easy. Cbc is open source, spun-off from IBM's early versions of CPLEX (source is [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc/browser/stable/2.8/Cbc/src)). Files CbcModel.cpp and CbcSolve.cpp only, have about 30,000 lines of C++ code together. [OpenSolver](http://opensolver.org/using-opensolver/), a Cbc wrapper and UI for VBA, has 6,754 lines written in VBA.

Comment: Yup, but once you create a matrix manipulation library, even in VBA, a simplex problem is extremely simple. I mean, I'd done something like that a couple a years ago and it took about a day to make one in VBA (i.e. if you are fully aware of the algorithm and know all the quirks and all). Making a very efficient one is a totally different game... but making one for say 400 variables is not too painful.